# There is no button "architecture"-in blender version 3.5.if I watch tutorial for blender 2.9. there is a button

Tags: objects

I need blender for interiors. The button "architecture" is missing. It gives the options for walls, windows ,doors. It should be in Layouts/Add/Mesh/Architecture, but in the new version there is no such a button. On the site of blender there is no option to download version 2.9 only 3.5. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you're talking about "Archimesh" which is an addon. You can activate it from the preferences windows.

Comment: Hi I tried preferences/ add ons/ ,but there is not "Archimesh"

Comment: I found it Mesh-Archimesh! You are great!!!! Thank you very much!

Comment: As @lemon says, those options are available from Blender's built-in Archimesh addon which is in all recent Blender versions if you have it enabled. If you really want to download older versions of Blender they are all available [here](https://download.blender.org/release/) right back to version 1.0.

Comment: I found it! Thank you very much!

Comment: When a problem is solved, should I do something to close the tag or delete the question? I am new

Comment: Just post an answer to your question explaining how you resolved your issue than u can mark the green checkmark to close it.

Comment: Many thanks to @lemon and all, who had trying to help!!!! The answer is Preference/ add ons/ add Mesh Archimesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Many thanks to @lemon and all, for your help)

The answer is Edit > Preferences >  Add Ons >  *Add Mesh: Archimesh*.

Comment: Ahh.. OK.. it's an answer. Great :). Eventually you can accept it for yourself by clicking the tick next door.